# Correct preposition for "competence"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which prepositions can be used with "competence"?

Specificially, which of the following examples are valid/legal:

- I have competence on computers
- I have competence with computers
- I have competence as a programmer
- Our company has competence in programming
- Our company has competence on programming
- Our company has competence with programming and cooking
- Our company has competence within the fields of programming and cooking
- Our company has several employees with competence with programming
- Our company has several employees with programming competence

Comment: Seriously, no one is going to say any of your examples are illegal!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say many of OP's examples are actually "illegal", but they're mostly pretty "ugly" to my ear. As [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=has+competence+in%2Chas+competence+with%2Chas+competence+as&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, any preposition other than "in" is *very* uncommon.

Comment: When I first had to use the word 'competence' in a sentence the preposition "over" suddenly came to mind. Has anybody considered it?

Comment: Is it your argument that the preposition depends on the word 'competence' and not on the word that follows the preposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "with" is the correct preposition in this case:

> I have competence with computers/Our company has competence with programming and cooking.

However, I would like to add that "competence" is not usually used in this case, but rather "competent".

E.g.:

> I am competent with computers

Comment: And be careful:  "competent with" is descriptive; "competent *at* " is disparaging, implying bare adequacy and no more: "Sure, he's competent at math, but he's no Einstein."

Comment: I disagree with "with". So does [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=competence+in%2Ccompetence+with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), by a factor of 10:1 in favour of "in".

Comment: I would recommend: *I have competence with computers,* but *I have competence in programming*. *I have competence with food,* but *I have competence in cooking.* See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to partially agree with both answers. If you are talking about an abstract field of study or occupation (physics, computing, auto mechanics, and so on), you are competent *in* it.

> I am competent in computing.

If you are talking about physical objects, you are competent *with* them:

> I am competent with computers.

Searching Google books for *competent with*, I find

"competent with food, handwriting, and knowledge of bookkeeping," "competent with peers," "competent with the predicting strategy," "competent with people."

Searching Google books for *competent in,* I find

"competent in research," "competent in traditions of culture A," "competent in the practice of homeopathy," "competent in the domestic arena."

Most hits for *competent in* and *competent with* don't seem to fall in the scope of the OPs question, so just counting Google hits doesn't really tell you anything.

Answer (score 1):

'In' seems to me the right preposition. Since one is competent 'in' something, the person would have competence 'in' that thing as well.